# Django Registration Redux custom registration form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, registration

I'm really confused how I can change the `registration_form` to ask the users about their first and last name.
I think I need to manipulate subclass `RegistrationView` from `registration.backends.simple.views` but I don't know how to do this to show **first and last name** in registration form.

Comment: Not yet! I created another profile model for first and last names. Would appreciate it if you kindly help me to implement it as I mentioned above.

Comment: How about changing (extending) the class `registration.forms.RegistrationForm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to sub-class RegistrationForm and add the fields you want.

Look at the source for the default forms on how to do so:

- https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/forms.py